# Writing to SQL database with Classic ASP

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I'm trying to pull some data down into my database.
I use Microsoft Webmatrix for easy development, with SQL database setup and working.

** UPDATE **
Tags and variables was mixed - sorry - now i get this error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: 'ConnectDB'

/writenote.asp, line 17
```

**Please don't look into security as this will run on a standalone unit with no internet access and only operator access.**

Below is what i use for input to database.

"Connect.asp":

```
<% 
dim strConnect
strConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(local);" & _
         "Database=HISTORICDATA;User ID=userid;Password=pw"
%>
<!-- METADATA TYPE="typelib"
 FILE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" -->
```

My form:

```
<form action="writenote.asp" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>New note for <% response.write(tagname) %></legend>

Time:<br />
<input type="datetime-local" name="timestamp" value="<% Response.Write Now %>" required><br />

Object:<br />
<input type="text" name="object" value="<% response.write(tagname) %>" required><br />

User:<br />
<input type="text" name="user" value="<% response.write(loginuser) %>" required><br />

Note:<br />
<textarea name="note" rows="10" cols="30" required></textarea>
<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Below here is the content of "writenote.asp":

```
<%

dim username,object,time,note,objConn,objs,query

username = Request.Form("user")
tag      = Request.Form("object")
time     = Request.Form("timestamp")
note     = Request.Form("note")

Set objConn = ConnectDB()
query       = "INSERT INTO notes (username,object,time,note) VALUES ('"& username &"','"& object &"','"& time &"','"& note &"')"
Set objs    = objConn.Execute(query)

Response.Redirect("notes.asp")
%>
```

Old problem:

When i fill in my form it keeps saying:

![Http 500 error]https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/501326/file-2730129857-png/blog-files/01-sharepoint-2013-the-website-cannot-display-the-page-http-500-500x249.png?t=1482420346935

I can't make it insert any data in my database and it keeps coming with http 500 error.

Comment: Your variables for `tag` and `object` are mixed up, not declared, and need a attention. Question: Do you know what year it is? :) Or, do you just enjoy working with old technology?

Comment: @R.Richards Thank you! Sometimes new eyes on the code is the solution. But now it comes up with another problem - I have updated the question.

Yes, I know its old tech, but this have to be running on an older browser application. So it is intentional. But i kinda forgot how ASP works ;'D

Comment: You might have missed to include a file where `ConnectDB()` is defined.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ You are absolutely right. I will figure out a way to do this.. Thank you :)

Comment: My advice? Throw Webmatrix and learn to program classic ASP yourself. Will take some time,  but once you learn, you won't depend on fancy things that you spend hours and days trying to figure out how they work and why something is not working. In the long run, it will save you tons of time and money. (to the company)

Comment: Older browser doesn't mean older technology. It just means that the HTML you emit needs to be basic. You can use ASP.Net MVC to emit a very basic web page that will run in any browser.

Comment: I use Webmatrix because it have a built-in SQL database. This is great for testing these scripts and it also comes with its own IIS installation - whats not to like for a out-of-the-box test environment?!
Anyway, I did a lot classic ASP/VBs ages ago and this is not the problem :)

Comment: If you like out-of-the-box environment. You should try Django. Easy, fast and also active language :)

Comment: @sumpen I will check it out :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In writenote.asp you can do like this

```
    <%
    dim username,object,time,note,dbInsert,dbOpen

    Set connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    dbOpen = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(local);UID=username;PWD=password;Database=HISTORICDATA "

    username = Request.Form("user")
    tag      = Request.Form("object")
    time     = Request.Form("timestamp")
    note     = Request.Form("note")

    connect.open(dbOpen)
    dbInsert       = "INSERT INTO notes (username,object,time,note) VALUES ('"& username &"','"& object &"','"& time &"','"& note &"')"
    connect.Execute(dbInsert)
    connect.Close
    Set Connect = Nothing

    Response.Redirect("notes.asp")
    %>
```

If you are doing db queries in lots of pages, Do as you have in your example. Put this in a 'connect.asp' or a config.asp':

```
Set connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        dbOpen = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(local);UID=username;PWD=password;Database=HISTORICDATA "
```

You can than include it into any page you are doing db queries with this code snippet:

```
<!-- #include file="connect.asp" -->
```

I must be included outside the ***<% %>***-tags.

And when doing queries use this syntax:

```
    connect.open(dbOpen)
    dbQuery = "put your query here" 
    connect.execute(dbQuery)    
    connect.Close
    Set Connect = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made it work though. I can see we have done it slightly the same way but your seems to be a little more nice to look at :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which worked. Thank you very much for your contribution and help.

In "Connect.asp" i connect to database and create recordset for which i use later on.

The document "notes.asp" gets the info needed through a cookie coming from elsewhere. This data is handled same place and not shown as this contains info not for public display :)

In the left section i create input for the SQL database. Most fields are readonly for the user as the input comes from the cookie and time.
The notes for the same tagname is shown in the right sections textarea. 
This data can also be printed (in an unordered way).

I'll post my code below, but not CSS. The VBs might be unordered but works like a charm.

Connect.asp:

```
<% 'include file
dim strConnect,objConn,objRecordSet

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConn.Open = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
           "Database=HISTORICDATA;User ID=sa;Password=PW;"

%>
<!-- METADATA TYPE="typelib"
 FILE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" -->
```

From my "notes.asp":

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<!-- #include file="connect.asp" -->
<!-- Cookie handling -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function printTextArea(notetxtarea)
{
 var elementRef = document.getElementById(notetxtarea);
 var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
 var uniqueName = new Date();
 var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
 var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');

 printWindow.document.write(elementRef.value);
 printWindow.document.close();
 printWindow.focus();
 printWindow.print();
 printWindow.close();
}
// -->
</script>
        <title>Notes for <% response.write(tagname) %></title>
    </head>
    <body onload="window.resizeTo(1000,900)">

<header>
<h1>Notes for <% response.write(tagname) %></h1>
<p>For use is now:</p>

<%
response.write("Object: " & tagname)
response.write("<br />")
response.write("User: " & loginuser)
%>

</header>

<section>

<form action="writenote.asp" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New note for <% response.write(tagname) %></legend>

<label for="tid">Time:</label>
<input type="datetime-local" id="tid" name="timestamp" value="<% Response.Write Now %>" readonly><br />

<label for="objekt">Object:</label>
<input type="text" id="objekt" name="object" value="<% response.write(tagname) %>" readonly><br />

<label for="bruger">User:</label>
<input type="text" id="bruger" name="user" value="<% response.write(loginuser) %>" readonly><br />

<p></p>Note (max. 300 chars):</p>
<textarea name="note" rows="11" cols="30" maxlength="300" required></textarea>
<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset">
        </fieldset>
</form>

</section>

<section>
<fieldset>
<legend>Notes for <% response.write(tagname) %></legend>
    <input type="button" value="Print Notes" onclick="JavaScript:printTextArea('notetxtarea');">
<textarea name="note" rows="23" cols="40" id="notetxtarea" readonly>
<%
dim strSQL,printStr
'Open the recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.notes WHERE tag = '" & tagname & "' ORDER BY time DESC"

set objRecordSet = objConn.Execute (strSQL)

'first of all determine whether there are any records
If objRecordSet.EOF Then
Response.Write("No records of " & tagname)

Else

Do While NOT objRecordSet.EOF  

Response.write(objRecordSet("time") & vbCrLf)
Response.write(objRecordSet("tag") & vbCrLf)
Response.write(objRecordSet("username")& vbCrLf)
Response.write(objRecordSet("note")& vbCrLf)
Response.write(vbCrLf)
Response.write("-----------------------")
Response.write(vbCrLf)
objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
End If

objRecordSet.Close
Set objRecordSet=nothing
objConn.Close
Set objConn=nothing

%>
</textarea>


</fieldset>

</section>



<div class="clearer"></div>
<footer>
<p>Things in my footer</p> 
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

From "writenote.asp":

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<!-- #include file="connect.asp" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Execute write to file</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<%
dim username,tag,time,note,query,objs

username = Request.Form("user")
tag      = Request.Form("object")
time     = Request.Form("timestamp")
note     = Request.Form("note")


objConn.Execute = "INSERT INTO dbo.notes (tag,username,time,note) VALUES ('"+ tag +"','"+ username +"','"+ time +"','"+ note +"')"


Response.Redirect("notes.asp")

objRecordSet.Close
Set objRecordSet=nothing
objConn.Close
Set objConn=nothing

%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's free tip =) If you are interested in best practise. You should not open the connection in the included _connect.asp_. You should do as my example where you _open connection_ -> _execute query_ -> _close connection_ -> _set recordset to nothing_. No code in between. You should also do GetRows() and not IF/ELSE with the recordset. Good luck! =)

Comment: Thank you @Sumpen :) I need to read a little more about this.

Comment: There may be other issues with your code, but among them, you are redirecting the "writenote.asp" page PRIOR to closing and deinstantiating your ADO objects.

Comment: @codemaker You are right. That part of code is also not existing anymore. Thank you.